# How to mark JAX-RS resource method as Deprecated for OpenAPI?

Tags: jax-rs, openapi, microprofile

I'm using MicroProfile OpenAPI with JAX-RS on Quarkus and would like to mark the resource as deprecated, ie. achieve the following result in the generated JSON:

```
get:
  ...
  deprecated: true
```

Marking the method as @Deprecated does not help. Any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by setting `deprecated` inside `@Operation`, i.e.:

```
    @Operation(
            deprecated = true,
            ...
    )
```